# Obtener el contenido de una URL en javascript a través de java

Tags: javascript, java, web, scrapy

Lo que quiero es obtener el contenido de una URL con javascript a través de java. De forma que pueda recuperar el valor a través de mi variable en java pero ejecutando el código javascript:

```
    page.executeJavaScript("javascript: {" +
          "document.getElementById(\"form_postalcode\").innerHTML "+
    +"};");
```

Comment: El contenido de una URL que te da Java con Javascript ?

Comment: Si. El tema es que cuando ejecuto el código Javascript a través de java me lleva a otra página. Trato de recuperar dicha nueva página web pero me devuelve la inicial antes de ejecutar el JavaScript. Por eso, quería intentar recuperar la página web a la que me lleva de esta forma.